# What type of data should you choose when you have a one-to-one or many-to-one relationship?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I was looking at Vaughn Vernon's DDD sample repository, and I am completely confused about what decision to make when dealing with one-to-one or many-to-one relationships with other aggregates or non-aggregates, as seen in the Discussion entity/model where one property is represented as an entity and another as an ID (value object). I am a bit lost.

He uses the following properties in the Discussion entity:

https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/domain/model/forum/Discussion.java

```
private Author author; // entity
private ForumId forumId; // value object
private Tenant tenant; // entity
```

Can you help me understand how to correctly choose the appropriate type?

Because if we talk to domain experts a discussion is related to a Forum, not to a forumID, it is something I still find difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's linked to Aggregate Roots. I haven't seen the code (and read the book many years ago), but for what I see `Discussion` is a root aggrate, so it should only refer to other Root Aggregates by ID. It looks like `Forum` is another Root Aggregate.

This 'barrier' between between Root Aggregates helps to manage complexity. It lowers cognitive load as the bounday of a root aggregate is clear and changes to one Root Aggregate cannot make changes in other Root Aggregates.

ForumId is considered a value object because it just represents a value. I know that sounds tautological, but bear in mind that most software out there represents ids as `long` or `UUID`. Without wrapping it in a more meaningful type. Having a 'long' doesn't make it clear to what aggregate/entity it refers to, or if it's just a random number that represents something else. Using value objects in this way is sometimes called microtypes.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that they are all value object when looking at the database schema and navigating deeper through the classes, and I thought they were other models :( https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/mysql/collaboration.sql

Comment: I hope this answered your question! It feels like the title of your questions points to something else :)